# HTML: Child elements have unexpected margins, DevTools shows none

Tags: html, css, margin

```css
.shwph-tab {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ffffff, #f0fbff, #ccfdff, #a4ffff, #94ffe3);
  background-size: cover, cover;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px grey ridge;
  padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
}

.shwph-tab-separator {
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #00979c;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.shwph-tab-left-side {
  width: 30%;
}

.shwph-tab-right-side {
  width: calc(70% - 43px)
}

.h-90p {
  height: 90%;
}

.longsec-child-preset-2 {
  min-height: 74vh;
}

.c-white {
  color: white;
}

.w-100p {
  width: 100%;
}

.fx {
  display: flex;
}

.fx-ai-c {
  align-items: center;
}

.fx-jc-c {
  justify-content: center;
}

.fx-dir-c {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.min-padding {
  padding: 10vh 0;
}

.bs-bb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brad-3px {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<section class="longsec-child-preset-2 c-white w-100p fx fx-jc-c fx-ai-c fx-dir-c min-padding bg-shwph bgs-full">
  <div class="shwph-tab fx fx-ai-c fx-dir-c bs-bb">
    <div>

    </div>

    <div class="h-90p w-100p">
      <div class="shwph-tab-left-side fx fx-ai-c fx-jc-c h-100p">

      </div>
      <div class="shwph-tab-separator brad-3px h-100p"></div>
      <div class="shwph-tab-right-side h-100p fx fx-ai-c fx-jc-c">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is some code of my website. The problem of mine concerns unexpected margins - all appearing in the element with `h-90p` and `w-100p` classes. All of them are only right and have size equal to the parent's minus their widths.

What I've done:

- Tried disabling the styles;
- Tried deleting sibling elements;
- Tried modifying the parent element;
- Researched the issue on the net, including the GPT.

All my efforts were fruitless. There is no possible external interference from stuff like js or php. All help is welcome.

PS For some reason, the separator has no color. I am unable to fix the problem.

PPS The numbers seem to be equal, so why the margin?

Comment: I'm not seeing any margin/padding on that element, could you include an image of what you are seeing? (The parent does have `40px` padding, I assume that's not what you mean?)

Comment: @DBS of course! I might even provide a live source in some short time.

Comment: @DBS The site, together with the prob, is here: https://shatterwares.com/

Comment: `margin-left + border-left-width + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-right-width + margin-right = width of containing block`  - This equality MUST hold. What you see is the browser adjusting the right margin to make the equality hold.

Comment: @Alohci I don't really understand... Could you elaborate some more, please?

Comment: The details are here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#blockwidth . In particular, see the bit about values being "over-constrained".

Comment: @Alohci so basically, using them together is forbidden? I don't really understand what I've done wrong, still...

Comment: "Forbidden" is not the right concept. Think of it more as a _contradiction_, The browser is making a change to the margin to compensate for that contradiction.